# Identify reverse idler of BCS mower

Tags: transmission, part-identification, lawnmower

I recently acquired a stripped down transmission/differential/wheel hub/brake from an old BCS 735 mower. This is a similar device (no engine, no wheels, no rear implement in my case):

[image: image of implement]

*https://www.tractorbynet.com/forums/threads/just-picked-up-a-used-bcs-737-how-did-i-do.370086/*

I have managed to get the gearbox and differential assembled again from being completely scattered around. However the reverse idler gear is completely worn down. It still kind of works, but it will fail soon enough. I do know the part number, but I cant find a single thing about it. I would like to machine a new gear, but I only have some guesses based on the worn down existing gear how it should look like. Preferrably I'd like to get the actual specs of it.

In the [service manual](https://s3.amazonaws.com/bcs-america/manuals/WSM.715-725-735-745.compressed.pdf) I can find the required parts information and it can be seen here:

[image: Image of part number 590.43071.3]

I was wondering if anyone recognizes this type of machine and happens to know more details about the reverse idler gear or at least a compatible alternative that can still be ordered, because with the part number in the manual I was not able to find anything.

Comment: Two things: 1) What you have pictured would be considered a soil tiller. Was calling it a mower a translation error? Or is what you are trying to fix completely different from what you have pictured? 2) On this site, we don't do product recommendations or assist with shopping (finding parts, in this case).

Comment: Regarding 1) Mower, tiller, nothing, it is a modular thing. It has a PTO where you can attach whatever you want. I have the skeleton without any implement as I have clearly mentioned in my question and my question is completely irrelevant to the implement.

Comment: So the tag "part identification" that immediately popped up is just a joke then?

Comment: Gotcha on the "mower, tiller, nothing". Seems like right now all you really have is a transmission from a BCS 735. As far as a "part-identification" tag, determining what a part is, is not a problem at all. Helping you find said part is a problem as it is considered parts shopping. The reason we don't do that is because information we find you today will be stale by tomorrow (or the next, whenever), which makes it useless down the line.

Comment: My primary goal is finding more reliable information about that part than me working with some calipers, like diameter, modulus or similar so that I could potentially machine it myself. Hence also why I asked about if there are models with the same part because maybe for those there are more details, since the BCS one does not seem to exist at all. The parts of a BCS 735 or it’s compatible siblings won’t change ever anymore

Comment: So, not asking us for help looking for the part, but rather if there is a more reliable part number or a cross reference. That we can help with :o) Just trying to ensure we are keeping things on-topic for the site. Sorry if it seemed like I was hassling you as that was not my intention.

Comment: Yea indeed, I realize as well now I was a bit in a hurry yesterday and my comments were unnecessarily harsh, sorry about that! Exactly, I searched with the part number and except a reference to the manual absolutely nothing comes up, nothing even from 15 years ago or so. I worded cross reference a bit too complicated in my question, but that was indeed my best guess on where to get more information :)